# trying to center .follow-btn using justify-content:center;

Tags: css, centering

```
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  header, footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  header .profile-thumbnail {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  header .profile-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  header .follow-btn {
    display: flex;
justify-content:center;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  }
  header .follow-btn button {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  header h3, header h4 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #inner p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #inner hr {
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  footer .stats {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  footer .stats strong {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  footer .stats .likes {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  footer .cta {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  footer .cta button {
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
</style>
<header>
  <img src="https://freecodecamp.s3.amazonaws.com/quincy-twitter-photo.jpg" alt="Quincy Larson's profile picture" class="profile-thumbnail">
  <div class="profile-name">
    <h3>Quincy Larson</h3>
    <h4>@ossia</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="follow-btn">
    <button>Follow</button>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="inner">
  <p>I meet so many people who are in search of that one trick that will help them work smart. Even if you work smart, you still have to work hard.</p>
  <span class="date">1:32 PM - 12 Jan 2018</span>
  <hr>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="Retweets">
      <strong>107</strong> Retweets
    </div>
    <div class="likes">
      <strong>431</strong> Likes
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cta">
    <button class="share-btn">Share</button>
    <button class="retweet-btn">Retweet</button>
    <button class="like-btn">Like</button>
  </div>
</footer>
```

So my question is, before I add Justify-content:center; to header .follow-btn, the button remains ont he left, if I add any justify type of data to this it goes to the right. Wether I use center or whatever. My question is Why?. I'm trying to learn the basics and this is a bit confusing considering I just finished the course stating that justify content center should push it to the middle of the x axis, but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are having: `margin: 0 0 0 auto;` into `header .follow-btn` that will align your button to the right because it will add a full margin to the left no matter what as your header is set with `display:flex;`.

Make margin like: `margin: auto 0;` if you want to align it horizontaly.

```html
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  header, footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  header .profile-thumbnail {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  header .profile-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  header .follow-btn {
    display: flex;
justify-content:center;
    margin: auto 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  header .follow-btn button {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  header h3, header h4 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #inner p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #inner hr {
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  footer .stats {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  footer .stats strong {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  footer .stats .likes {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  footer .cta {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  footer .cta button {
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
</style>
<header>
  <img src="https://freecodecamp.s3.amazonaws.com/quincy-twitter-photo.jpg" alt="Quincy Larson's profile picture" class="profile-thumbnail">
  <div class="profile-name">
    <h3>Quincy Larson</h3>
    <h4>@ossia</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="follow-btn">
    <button>Follow</button>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="inner">
  <p>I meet so many people who are in search of that one trick that will help them work smart. Even if you work smart, you still have to work hard.</p>
  <span class="date">1:32 PM - 12 Jan 2018</span>
  <hr>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="Retweets">
      <strong>107</strong> Retweets
    </div>
    <div class="likes">
      <strong>431</strong> Likes
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cta">
    <button class="share-btn">Share</button>
    <button class="retweet-btn">Retweet</button>
    <button class="like-btn">Like</button>
  </div>
</footer>
```